# Wildcard Queries with multiple words in Lucene

Tags: java, apache, api, lucene

I am developing a sample API that accepts the `ColumnName` and `value` that is to be searched. The API searches and returns the related results in XML format. I am using `StandardAnalyser` of Lucene. I have a search phrase `"Central West*"` for a `COMPANYNAME` field. I have 2 records with`COMPANYNAME` field set to `"CentralWest"` in my database. When I search with the above stated search phrase, I am getting those two records as my result. 
But when I search with `"Central We*"` I am getting no results. I dont know thats the problem I am facing. I read like using `QueryParser` is the best way. Is there is no way to provide the solution for the problem in `StandardAnalyser` and whats the problem am I facing?

Comment: Have you tried fuzzy search?

Comment: Thanks @DanielJipa. No. I havent tried the Fuzzy search. Will that be a solution?

Comment: I use when searching for phrases that may differ in words order. See documentation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `StandardAnalyzer` and have results for phrase `"Central West*"` but not for `Central We*`.

First of all: StandardAnalyzer does not split CentralWest. So you can not match CentralWest with phrase "Central West" ([WordDelimiter Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) would do).

Most likely you are using a query parser without wildcard support. And there are few query parsers with wildcard support in phrases like [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html).

Without wildcard support the StandardAnalyzer does not differ between ´West*´ and ´West´ so you have a match. `We*`and `We` are treaded like `we`, so you have no match.